# Magento 2 Block ordering/moving: how to get of element name(or elements list) and destination elements name to move the element

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, reorder

May be this is not new to you, but have to ask this because of i cant get most answer what i want So asking as new.

```
<move element="minicart" destination="panel-header" before="header-links" />
```

This is the scenario what I have to get the element name or destination name like,

- go to store > configuration > Advance >developer > Debug > Enabled
  Template Path Hints for Storefront > ON IT.
- See the `TEMPLATE LINK` go to the template in `vender > magento > module directory > view ..... layout > default.xml` and see for file name get the name.

ANY OTHER solution TO GET name?

Comment: Hello @amit-bera, can i ask what you edit in this question!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MSP DevTools: https://github.com/magespecialist/mage-chrome-toolbar .

It will sohw you Magento information and specific blocks information such as: name in layout, block type, etc...

Is it what you are looking for?

[image]

Comment: Let me check @RiccardoT.

Comment: See my updated post, I attached a screenshot of blocks inspector.

Comment: I will check it tommorow as have to go, good bye for now. and thanks for you efforts

Comment: Having issue after installation done.
as per the instruction for Magento2 installation all installation done. But the fourth point about 'go to Store > Configuration > MageSpecialist > DevTools'. I cant found MAGESPECIALIST in STORE>CONFIG.

Comment: Check you correctly followed installation procedure and flushed cache. Otherwise post an issue on github. I'm sure it works

Comment: all done, but not get the "MageSpecialist " under STORE>>CONFIG

Comment: Submit a ticket on github. This is not the right place.

Comment: Just for other future user. Problem fixed here: https://github.com/magespecialist/mage-chrome-toolbar/issues/6